# Client to server connection only sending not receiving

Tags: client-server, send, socks

This is my case, I have a server listening for connections, and a client that I'm programming now. The client has nothing to receive from the server, yet it has to be sending status updates every 3 minutes.

I have the following at the moment:

```
    WSAStartup(0x101,&ws);
    sock = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
    sa.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sa.sin_port = htons(PORT_NET);
    sa.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1"); 
    connect(sock,(SOCKADDR*)&sa,sizeof(sa));
    send(sock,(const char*)buffer,128,NULL);
```

How should my approach be? Can I avoid looping recv?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's rather dependant on what behaviour you want and your program structure.
By default a socket will block on any read or write operations, which means that if your try and have your server's main thread poll the connection, you're going to end up with it 'freezing' for 3 minutes or until the client closes the connection.

The absolute simplest functional solution (no multithreadding) is to set the socket to non-blocking, and poll in in the main thread. It sounds like you want to avoid doing that though.

The most obvious way around that is to make a dedicated thread for every connection, plus the main listener socket. Your server listens for incoming connections and spawns a thread for each stream socket it creates. Then each connection thread blocks on it's socket until it receives data, and either handles it itself or shunts it onto a shared queue.
That's a bulky and complex solution - multiple threads which need opening and closing, shared resources which need protecting.

Another option is to set the socket to non-blocking (Under win32 use setsockopt so set a timeout, under *nix pass it the O_NONBLOCK flag). That way it will return control if there's no data available to read. However that means you need to poll the socket at reasonable intervals ("reasonable" being entirely up to you, and how quickly you need the server to act on new data.)

Personally, for the lightweight use you're describing I'd use a combination of the above: A single dedicated thread which polls a socket (or an array of nonblocking sockets) every few seconds, sleeping in between, and simply pushed the data onto a queue for the main thread to act upon during it's main loop.

There are a lot of ways to get into a mess with asynchronous programs, so it's probably best to keep it simple and get it working, until you're comfortable with the control flow.

Comment: What if I close the connection every time I send something, and open a new connection at the next time I need to send something, in this way I'll avoid the blocking. How does that sound?

Comment: Yeah, you can do that (And indeed you may as well, if you're only pushing status updates). The problem is that the server is going to be blocking on accept(), not just when reading data. Basically your server can't guarantee when the connection is going to occur and hence needs to be constantly listening. You could set a timeout (on both ends) and rely on both sides knowing the time they're meant to form a connection, but that's a tad prone to error. Edit: But if the only thing your server needs to do is process status updates, then yes that'd work fine.

Comment: Well I don't mind if the server is constantly listening. My original problem was that I was calling send() without closing the connection, and only the first status would be send, and I've read here in a similar case (http://stackoverflow.com/q/8347107/777510) that I needed to be calling recv and send in a loop to avoid this, and what I am asking is if I can avoid that loop in some way, perhaps by sending and closing the connection. So I should be fine with that?

Comment: Ah, ok then. You don't need to loop on the client, but you will need to loop on the server; To my understanding of stream sockets it's impossible to avoid that. The client can open connection->send data->close connection (or leave it open), whenever it needs to. Meanwhile the server will start listening->loop[accept connection, receive data] (Or start listening->accept connection->loop[receive data] if you leave the connection open (but that will only be able to accept one client ever connecting))